# Android NDK REST Client

Tags: android, c++, boost, libcurl

I am looking to create a library in C++ to make simple GET/POST calls on Android.  My hope is that I will be able to share the library across platforms.  From a simplicity / compatibility standpoint, is there any significant difference between utilizing libcurl vs boost asio, or am I on the wrong path?